# Copy resources with frank and cucumber

Tags: iphone, cucumber, bdd

I have a iPhone project where i use frank and cucumber for acceptance testing.

My application has a feature to collect files from the documents directory and index them in the applications database.

I want to test this feature with cucumber. But this means i have to copy files to the applications documents directory.

My questions are:

- How do i dynamically make step definitions to copy files?
- Where do place the resources before they get copied? In what folder structure?
- How do i reach these files from my step definitions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We created a helper function to do something like this for injecting images into the simulator gallery..

```
def init_simulator_images(num_images)
  (1..num_images.to_i).each do |n|
    target_file = "IMG_000#{n}.JPG"
    begin
      File.stat("#{ENV['simulator_media_path']}/#{target_file}")
    rescue Errno::ENOENT
      app_exec 'FEX_loadPhotoLibraryImage:', "test/#{target_file}"
    end
  end
end
```

and then on the native code side, we have a helper class called FEX_Helper to aid in anything where we need to modify the app at runtime (RubyMotion code but v. similar to objective-c except for the syntax):

```
def FEX_loadPhotoLibraryImage(imageStr)
  img = UIImage.imageNamed(imageStr)
  UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, nil, nil, nil)
end
```

Lastly the simulator media path is defined thusly:

```
def simulator_media_path
  "#{self.simulator_version_path}/Media/DCIM/100APPLE"
end

def simulator_path
  "/Users/#{self.user}/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator"
end

def simulator_version_path
  "#{self.simulator_path}/#{self.simulator_version}"
end
```

Hope that helps someone trying to inject files into the simulator for testing.

Mark